# Meteor.user() is undefined inside a function

Tags: meteor

I have this template helper

```
Template.foo.helpers
  'bar':->
    console.log(Meteor.user().profile)
  'baz':->
    console.log(Meteor.user().profile)
  'buzz':->
    console.log(Meteor.user().profile)
```

And it logs the user object flawlessly.

But when I try to use it outside of the template helper it returns an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined`

Like this

```
checkProfile=(profile)->
  console.log profile

Template.foo.helpers
  'bar':checkProfile(Meteor.user().profile)
  'baz':checkProfile(Meteor.user().profile)
  'buzz':checkProfile(Meteor.user().profile)
```

I think that it executes the function before the Meteor.user() is loaded but when I try to log `Meteor.userId` inside the checkProfile, ex:

```
checkProfile=(profile)->
  console.log Meteor.userId()
  console.log profile
```

even

```
checkProfile=(profile)->
  console.log Meteor.userId()
  console.log(Meteor.user())
```

It logs the userId asap but still returns an uncaught error.

Now I concluded that `Meteor.userId()` is always available at the start of meteor and `Meteor.user()` object is loaded after?

Please literate me for this conclusion as these little things may become a big problem in my code in the future. Thanks.

**Side Note:**

I'm sure that the user is logged in because I'm testing error tests when the user is loggedIn. It's just when the page refreshes, the code runs and returns that error when it tries to run Meteor.user()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is caused by trying to access "profile" on undefined object. So it is not connected with `checkProfile` function.

Template's helpers are wrapped with `Deps.autorun`, it means that if you put reactive data source (like `Meteor.user()`) inside helper then helper will be rerun every time reactive data source is changed.

Consider using guards in your helper:

```
var user = Meteor.user();
var profile = user && user.profile;
if(profile){
  checkProfile(profile);
}
```

Above code will run few times - every time data from `Meteor.user()` is changed.

See how it works here : 
http://meteorpad.com/pad/j2bqKeMfuuLpbn2TW

Create account, open console and then refresh meteor app to see logs.

#### Side Note

You can check if you are logging in :

```
if(Meteor.loggingIn()){
  ...
}
```

Comment: This was the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling checkProfile inside a publication by any chance? If so, you need to use publication's this.userId